# Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4 when using tf.models.modelFromJSON

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I tried training a sentiment analysis model and loading it onto tensorflow.js However, when I attempted to do so, I got this error message:

`Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4 when using tf.models.modelFromJSON`

Here are some of the important parts of my development:

Python:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, 1000, input_length=65-1),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5,
                strides=1, padding="causal",
                activation="relu",
                input_shape=[None, 1]),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(),
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax"),
])
```

```
! tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \
                       /content/covid_td_1.h5 \
                      /content/covid_tc_02
```

I then turned my model.json file into a javascript file and assigned it to a `const` variable.

model.json

```
export const modelJSON = {
    "format": "layers-model",
    "generatedBy": "keras v2.4.0",
    "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v3.3.0",
    "modelTopology": {
        "keras_version": "2.4.0",
        "backend": "tensorflow",
        "model_config": {
            "class_name": "Sequential",
            "config": {
                "name": "sequential",
                "layers": [{
                    "class_name": "InputLayer",
                    "config": {
                        "batch_input_shape": [null, 64],
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "sparse": false,
                        "ragged": false,
                        "name": "embedding_input"
                    }
                }, {
                    "class_name": "Embedding",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "embedding",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "batch_input_shape": [null, 64],
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "input_dim": 10000,
                        "output_dim": 1000,
                        "embeddings_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "RandomUniform",
                            "config": {
                                "minval": -0.05,
                                "maxval": 0.05,
                                "seed": null
                            }
                        },
                        "embeddings_regularizer": null,
                        "activity_regularizer": null,
                        "embeddings_constraint": null,
                        "mask_zero": false,
                        "input_length": 64
                    }
                }, {
                    "class_name": "Conv1D",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "conv1d",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "batch_input_shape": [null, null, 1],
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "filters": 64,
                        "kernel_size": [5],
                        "strides": [1],
                        "padding": "causal",
                        "data_format": "channels_last",
                        "dilation_rate": [1],
                        "groups": 1,
                        "activation": "relu",
                        "use_bias": true,
                        "kernel_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "GlorotUniform",
                            "config": {
                                "seed": null
                            }
                        },
                        "bias_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "Zeros",
                            "config": {}
                        },
                        "kernel_regularizer": null,
                        "bias_regularizer": null,
                        "activity_regularizer": null,
                        "kernel_constraint": null,
                        "bias_constraint": null
                    }
                }, {
                    "class_name": "MaxPooling1D",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "max_pooling1d",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "strides": [2],
                        "pool_size": [2],
                        "padding": "valid",
                        "data_format": "channels_last"
                    }
                }, {
                    "class_name": "GlobalAveragePooling1D",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "global_average_pooling1d",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "data_format": "channels_last"
                    }
                }, {
                    "class_name": "Dense",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "dense",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "units": 24,
                        "activation": "relu",
                        "use_bias": true,
                        "kernel_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "GlorotUniform",
                            "config": {
                                "seed": null
                            }
                        },
                        "bias_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "Zeros",
                            "config": {}
                        },
                        "kernel_regularizer": null,
                        "bias_regularizer": null,
                        "activity_regularizer": null,
                        "kernel_constraint": null,
                        "bias_constraint": null
                    }
                }, {
                    "class_name": "Dense",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "dense_1",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "units": 5,
                        "activation": "softmax",
                        "use_bias": true,
                        "kernel_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "GlorotUniform",
                            "config": {
                                "seed": null
                            }
                        },
                        "bias_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "Zeros",
                            "config": {}
                        },
                        "kernel_regularizer": null,
                        "bias_regularizer": null,
                        "activity_regularizer": null,
                        "kernel_constraint": null,
                        "bias_constraint": null
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "training_config": {
            "loss": "categorical_crossentropy",
            "metrics": [
                [{
                    "class_name": "MeanMetricWrapper",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "accuracy",
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "fn": "categorical_accuracy"
                    }
                }]
            ],
            "weighted_metrics": null,
            "loss_weights": null,
            "optimizer_config": {
                "class_name": "Adam",
                "config": {
                    "name": "Adam",
                    "learning_rate": 0.0010000000474974513,
                    "decay": 0.0,
                    "beta_1": 0.8999999761581421,
                    "beta_2": 0.9990000128746033,
                    "epsilon": 1e-07,
                    "amsgrad": false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "weightsManifest": [{
        "paths": ["group1-shard1of10.bin", "group1-shard2of10.bin", "group1-shard3of10.bin", "group1-shard4of10.bin", "group1-shard5of10.bin", "group1-shard6of10.bin", "group1-shard7of10.bin", "group1-shard8of10.bin", "group1-shard9of10.bin", "group1-shard10of10.bin"],
        "weights": [{
            "name": "conv1d/kernel",
            "shape": [5, 1000, 64],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }, {
            "name": "conv1d/bias",
            "shape": [64],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }, {
            "name": "dense/kernel",
            "shape": [64, 24],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }, {
            "name": "dense/bias",
            "shape": [24],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }, {
            "name": "dense_1/kernel",
            "shape": [24, 5],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }, {
            "name": "dense_1/bias",
            "shape": [5],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }, {
            "name": "embedding/embeddings",
            "shape": [10000, 1000],
            "dtype": "float32"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is where I initialize the model.

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {modelJSON} from './file (1)/content/covid_tc_02/model';



const model = tf.models.modelFromJSON(modelJSON).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.summary)
});
```

I am using tensorflow.js with react, if that helps.

I tried clearing the backend and restarting my runtime, but that did not work.

What is going on? Why isn't my model working properly?

Please message for more information if it is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't that possible to load a model locally using tensorflow.js(at least for me). Instead, I put the model into a github repository and loaded the model by using that link

Comment: Are you using React? I have loaded a model locally with Tensorflow.js before. I think the main issue is that you converted the file into a Javascript file and added the `export const`.

Comment: yes, i used react. I wanted a way to access the json file, so I converted it into javascript. I guess that's where the error came from. I used a github repo instead

Comment: Yeah if you keep it as it is it should work.